# If video speed increase by 2x, total time is reduced by 50%. How do I understand this with math? Please recommend basic resources for my skill level..

Tags: algebra-precalculus, self-learning, education, percentages

**Problem:** If you increase the speed of a video by 2x, you're reducing the total time by 50%. I have no understanding of how to calculate this, or how I got to this outcome.

**Request:** Please recommend exactly what specific topics I should learn and understand.

**Continuation Of Problem:** For example, if I increase playback speed by 2.5x, I have no idea what % the total time is reduced by. It's likely around ~66% or something, but I've no idea how to calculate this. Or more simply, I don't understand how to do this in math.

---

**Please recommend** in comments or answers (doesn't matter; the important thing is being helpful):

- online textbooks or any other resources specifically on practical math for everyday life

Other sources like Khan Academy has a lot of math that isn't useful or needed in everyday life.

---

I wish there was a math curriculum that specifically listed the top 10 or so specific topics for practical math, and the math topics that tend to be more useful relative to other topics

Whatever specific topic the question/problem I asked here should be on that top 10, 20 or whatever

I'm highly knowledgeable and understand many concepts in many academic fields/areas outside of math (that don't require math), but I don't understand whatever basic math topic this is. I'm assuming the math-orientated had given this specific topic a specific label/word -- as to make communication easier as well as a host of many other benefits.

---

It's generally said and understood that math is easier to learn via programming, but I do not know of any good sources, or if someone has made this yet as of 2017

Side note: I support all the people making progress in how math is being taught at all levels, besides the most abstract/theoretical. Please do not recommend any academic or theoretical math outside of the kind of practical resources that was asked for.

Comment: You should take a look at Proportionality. More precisely, Inverse Proportionality. Read this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)#Inverse_proportionality

Comment: Oh. And this link contains references... ;-)

Comment: Yep... super basic topic... classed under 'ratios', which is a subset of 'elementary mathematics' and 'algebra'.... these references are highly advanced and complicate/confuse things needlessly. I need a resource where I can learn/understand this and the other topics (that are useful to everyday life). This is an encyclopedia, which is largely historical. I read almost everything besides the math topics. I can't learn math like this. I need an actual learning resource.

Comment: @ambw Try here: http://www.elitetuition.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/GCSE_Maths_Revision_Higher.pdf.

Comment: What exactly do you classify as practical?I could list practical uses for about every precalculus topic,I also feel that Khan academy has one of the best easy to learn resources,and at least 70% of the lets say theoretical questions can be "translated" into practical problems/solutions.

Comment: For the specific problem you mentioned, is it obvious to you that if you increase the speed of the video by 2x, then the video will play in only half the time? If that is obvious, then it seems like the gap lies in your understanding of percentages. So perhaps the thing to do is learn percentages from scratch, using a source such as Khan Academy. (In fact, maybe you should work your way through the Khan Academy knowledge map from the very beginning up to the level of pre-algebra. Anything at the level of pre-algebra is surely practical -- fractions, decimals, percentages...)

Comment: The Khan Academy knowledge map is not just videos, by the way, it's an actual learning system where you answer math problems to prove your proficiency and progress through the knowledge map. I recommend giving it a try -- actually doing the problems and earning the badges.

Comment: I had already in the past done 'ratios' from scratch, and it did not give the understanding I was looking for. Understanding fundamentals and patterns is significantly different from knowledge. I'm looking for rare sources that can show/explain basic math concepts at a very high level using innovative and nontraditional methods. For example, I've asked basic questions to the answers so far, and those are the kind of questions I'm looking for answers on. I'm likely looking for sources that have a large base of understanding & knowledge in many other areas/fields on top of math knowledge.

Comment: Perhaps try *Complete Mathematics* (in the *Teach Yourself* series) by Neill and Johnson. This particular kind of problem might be addressed in the chapters "Percentages" and "Ratio and Proportion." If you want to improve your math skills overall, not just for this kind of problem, you could work through the whole book on your own and periodically discuss your progress with a tutor. By the way, it's very difficult to find explanations of basic math that are "innovative and nontraditional." If you've repeatedly had difficulties, then get one-on-one help from a teacher.

Comment: This Khan video on percent I watched is bad, it explains basically nothing to me, and he repeats in fragments what he's writing on the board like 3 times for like everything. It's so unpolished, all the Khan video are trash. I've seem actually good content in this lifetime. "very difficult to find" -- well that's why society needs this already in 2017. Most people in society aren't doing anything innovative is the problem, only the rare few (proportionally) are doing things that actually matters in any given lifetimes throughout the generations and centuries, and it's always been the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would actually recommend looking at this at a physics view point.

The basic equation for constant-velocity motion is $x=vt$, where $x$ stands for the place, $v$ for the velocity, and $t$ for time.

You can look at $v$ as the number of frames per second ("the speed of the video"), $t$ as the time it takes to watch the video, and $x$ as the total number of frames in the video.

In the question you are asking, we have the same $x$ for any velocity (the number of frames don't change). So we are solving $vt=const$. In case the speed is say $\times 2.5$, the time must be $\times \frac{1}{2.5}$ for us to have the same constant.

The remaining part is to understand the relation between a number such as $\frac{1}{2.5}$ and precentage. This is the definition of precentage - $ 1\%\ =\frac{1}{100}$. So we have $\frac{1}{2.5}=\frac{40}{100}=40\%\ $, and the time would be $40\%\ $ of the original time.

To end my answer, I would recommend some generic middle school algebra book, these things are usually covered quite good there.

Comment: For the 3 letters, the only one that's unclear is x. I'm not sure what to put there or how I would understand what to put there. You of course did and put what's suppose to be there: 'total frames'. Looks like x is constant, but there's so many other things that are constant that I can put there. For example, a 'button on the UI' is constant but it doesn't seem like it would make sense to put that as v. But how do I figure out what to put in there for all cases and problems of this pattern? Is there a mathematical way to go about this? Or I don't understand.. **What do I read or learn?**

Comment: What chances in time? only the number of frames you have watched. Also, if you think about the relevant units - if we agree that time is in seconds, and the velocity is frames per second, we must get that the place is frames/sec *sec which is frames.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'chances in time'. Explaining is hard. Should read all the other comments.

Comment: *changes in time, sorry

Comment: I meant x when I wrote v on that line: "would make sense to put that as v" -- where's a list of all 'changes in time' words so i know what to put in x?

Answer (score 3):

This is what is called *inversely proportional*.  Think about this example: it takes $1$ man $24$ hours to build a wall. However, if there were $2$ men, they'd get it done *twice as fast*, so you *half* how long it takes --- it would take two of them $12$ hours to build together. For $3$ people, it would take a *third* of the time, so it would only take $8$ hours. In general, if there are $n$ people, it would take $24/n$ hours to build this wall.

Your video is the same --- you're playing it *twice as fast*, so it only plays for *half* the time. If you play it at $2.5$ times speed, then it plays for $1/2.5$ percent of the original time.

**EDIT:**

The law of proportionality is evident in a lot of things. You may conjecture that sunny skies improve ice cream sales; or that better tasing food will cost more; or that more time in the sun will give you a darker tan. These are each examples of relationships that are *directly proportional*, since an increase in one causes an increase in the other. Conversely, an *increase* in rainy weather may cause a *decrease* in ice cream sales, or an *increase* in burgers eaten per week may *decrease* how long you live, both of which are examples of *inverse proportionality*. Now, these are not *strict* relationships since there are more factors there, but I'm trying to convey the idea of proportional relationships.

We will move to 'stricter' relationships. Say we can buy a box of five pens. If I buy *one* box, I get *five* pens. If I buy *two* boxes, I get *ten* pens. If I buy $n$ boxes, I get $5\times n$ pens. The relationship is *directly proportional* and follows the formula
$$
y = 5 \times x
$$
where $y$ is the number of pens, and $x$ is the number of boxes bought. It is nonsense to talk of a 'proof' in this sense --- the relation is obvious (I hope!). In general, the formula for *direct proportionality* is
$$
y = k \times x
$$
where $x$ and $y$ are your variables (you have to think which is which --- there's not just some 'magic formula' for every possible situation, you have to apply some logic yourself), and $k$ is the proportionality factor. In the pens example, this is five. There are many more examples of this relationship, but you just need to *think* which was round it goes --- that is, if I buy *more* boxes, does it make sense that I get *more* or *less* pens? Of course, you get *more*!

The other type of proportionality is *inverse proportionality*. This happens when an *increase* in one variable cause a *decrease* in the other. For my wall example, does it make sense that *more* workers means that it takes *longer* to build the wall? Of course not! (Unless the workers stand about chatting all day, but we're not considering that kind of situation.)

The standard formula for inverse proportionality is
$$
y = \frac{k}{x}
$$
where the variables are the same as before. You have to look at your situation and figure out which variable matches up with which letter in the formula. For your video example, you actually set $k = 1$ because you are considering only one video, but we follow this thought process:

"My video plays for some amount of time. If I *speed up* the video, do I expect it to play for a longer or for a shorter amount of time? Since it's playing faster, it plays *more frames in each second*. If it's playing more frames in each second, and it's playing the same amount of frames, logic dictates that it must play for a shorter amount of time (again, I stress that there *is no formal proof for this in the sense that you are talking*, you just need to think about what makes sense). If I play it at $2\times$ the speed, then it can either double or half because of the $2$. If it can't double since that doesn't make sense, *it has to half* (this is shown Mathematically in the other two answers). Now, we know that the relationship is $(2\times)$ speed $\implies$ $\frac{1}{2}$ the play time, we can jump to the formula
$$
(s\times)\text{ sped up} \implies \frac{1}{s}\text{ times the original play time.}"
$$
Again, this is 'proved' Mathematically in the other two answers, but it's such an obvious relationship that the above steps certainly suffice.

Comment: As for further reading, Khan Academy is absolutely fantastic. You may not see the 'real life' applications of many of his videos directly, but a great deal of them are the foundations for bigger topics that do have applications in the real world. It seems that you need to learn a lot of the fundamentals of Mathematics --- I would suggest learning everything in the Mathematics GCSE schedule (or any foreign equivalent). There is very little Mathematics taught at the level that doesn't have applications, whether you can see it or not.

Comment: So looks like the formula generally at least is [total time taken] : [number of people, speed, or whatever the variable is] -- but of course this isn't helping me understand anything. I mean, do I always put the variable (the number that is being changed) in the second slot? Saying that something is 'twice as fast' equates to 'half the time' is a HUGE jump. How in the world did we get there? Why is it that 3 people is 1/3 the time? Every single step from the starting point (2x) to the end point (50% less) needs to be explained FULLY -- IN ABSOLUTE DETAIL. That's what understanding means,

Comment: At this moment, I don't understand this. I have the formula and therefore the answer -- 1/2.51/2.5 percent of the original time -- to this one specific instance of the larger fundamental problem, but how in the world do I know and understand this? Without it being told to me? Khan Academy does not teach this **understanding**. Link me proof. I'd be happy to be proven mistaken. Looking at the link you commented under the main question, this is what I'm talking about: this are just things that give me rules to apply, but these kind of things are not giving me high-level understanding.

Comment: @ambw There is no book that teaches this 'understanding' --- for the most part, this relationship is taken to be obvious. I seriously doubt that there is a 'proof' for it as well --- though the other two answers would be the closest thing to a proof. This understanding comes from two places: taking to someone about it (like now), or by thinking about it and deducing the result for yourself. I will attempt to elaborate my answer to explain this.

Comment: @ambw Again, I'm going to stress the fact that there _is no book that goes this in depth_. If you're at school or college, talk to a teacher/lecturer about it. But, I would **strongly** suggest just sitting down and **thinking about it yourself**. Try writing out some of your own examples --- attempt to figure out these relationships, and what would _actually make sense_. Thinking independently and trying your own examples _is so vastly important_ for coming to a full understanding of simple laws like these.

Comment: That means that someone or a team has to make a interactive (using programming) video/website that shows/make visual 1) all key variations and relationships of a specific topic/concept so we can understand the core pattern easier -- "Thinking independently and trying your own examples" -- "attempt to figure out these relationships" and 2) enable the learner to 'explore' it FULLY as demoed by Bret Victor (UC Berkeley) in 'Explorable Explanations' like 6+ or so years back on his website. **How about the text 'Mathematical Thinking' (2012) by Keith Devlin (Stanford)?** .pdf is googlable

Comment: People would stress 'thinking' and 'figuring it out'. This 'thinking' can be taught. There's all kinds of 'thinking' within all other fields and for some also within a specific field. People would say it's 'obvious' but that does not explain/show anything. For example, if I say the sky is 'blue' -- that's not 'obvious' -- absolutely nothing in this universe/world is 'obvious'. I would need to explain what blue means, some things about semantics-linguistics, the various shades of blue, color, and eventually go into physics and light, and astrophysics until we get the limits of understanding

Comment: @ambw No they don't. There are some things that are objective truths. It is also common in the community to _leave some work for the reader_ when it comes to self explanations. Being able to piece parts of a proof together to get an understanding of the whole proof is part pf the learning experience; giving someone all the information straight away prohibits free thinking and original thought. There are some things that you are expected to learn yourself, and this is totally fair.

Comment: "objective truths" -- to those who are indoctrinated in this way of thinking, sure. "some things that are objective truths" - oh? well like everything else in history i want a community that actually makes progress and doesn't do things in the outdated way. im very upset by the low quality of the learning materials and commented about a khan academy video under the OP post. I need quality, innovative content to learn this boring shit. I do not agree with your views on the topic and it sounds like a person who was trained in an outdated way. This is why startups matter and are needed.

Comment: Stack Exchange _is_ that community. The reason no one develops on this topic is because people don't usually struggle with it --- irrespective of ones background, my explanation or the Physics explanation are two of the explanations that are easiest to understand for this topic. We're not 'set in our ways' --- it's like asking why dividing by two is the same and multiplying by a half, there's only so many ways it can be explained without overdoing it! I stand by the comment that some things should be left to you when they are simple steps like these as it helps you to develop yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about this in terms of something a little more concrete. Think of a sprinter running a 100-meter dash. If they run $5$ meters every second, how long will it take them to complete the race? Well, they must cover a the distance $D = 100~\text{m}$ at a speed (or rate) of $r = 5~\text{m}/\text{s}$. This will take them a time $t = \frac{D}{v} = \frac{100~\text{m}}{5~\text{m}/\text{s}} = 20~\text{s}$. I have derived this from the equation $D = r\times t$, which says that one travels a distance $D$ when moving at a speed $r$ for a length of time $t$. Notice how the units ($\text{m}$ and $\text{s}$) are treated algebraically, just as if they were numbers or variables. In particular, the unit of meters cancels as a common factor in the division, and the unit of seconds ends up in the numerator.

In terms of your video example, the distance $D$ is the length of the video. So, say we have a video that is three minutes long: $D = 3~\text{min} = 3~\text{min}\times\frac{60~\text{s}}{1~\text{min}} = 180~\text{s}$.

> We can multiply by the *conversion factor* of $\frac{60~\text{s}}{1~\text{min}}$ since it equals $1$, and since multiplying by $1$ leaves a number unchanged.

If we play the video at normal speed ($1$x), then we have playback rate $r = 1~\text{s}/\text{s}$. Of course, in this case, we have that the playback time $t = \frac{D}{v} = \frac{180~\text{s}}{1~\text{s}/\text{s}} = 180~\text{s} = D$ is the same as the length of the video.

What happens when we consider playback rate of 2.5x? In this case, we have $r = 2.5~\text{s}/\text{s}$, so that $t = \frac{D}{r} = \frac{180~\text{s}}{2.5~\text{s}/\text{s}} = 72~\text{s}$. So, at 2.5x playback, a $3$-minute ($D=180~\text{s})$ video only takes $1$ minute and $12$ seconds ($t=72~\text{s}$) to watch. This is a reduction of $1$ minute and $48$ seconds ($D-t=108~\text{s}$), which is a reduction by $\frac{D-t}{D} = \frac{108~\text{s}}{180~\text{s}} = 0.6 = 60\%$. (Thus your guess of $66\%$ was rather close.)

Takeaway: The unit of the distance $D$ can be anything and the equation will still apply, assuming the rate $r$ remains constant for the duration $t$. In the sprinter example, $D$ was traditional distance, length. In the video example, it was (video playback) time.

But it could be pizzas. Final example: If I have to fill an order of 15 pizzas and can make one pizza in 7 minutes, how long will it take to finish all of the pizzas? Well, our *distance* is $D = 15~\text{pizzas}$ and our rate is $r = \frac{1~\text{pizza}}{7~\text{min}}$. Thus it would take $t = \frac{D}{r} = \frac{15~\text{pizzas}}{\frac{1~\text{pizza}}{7~\text{min}}} = 15\times 7~\text{min} = 105~\text{min}$ to complete this order.

Comment: 1) How I do I know what equation to use? 2) How do I know what numbers to put into what letters? 3) I can put anything into D? - "distance D can be anything" - can I put the 'speed'? 4) In your example, [distance] = 100 m, so then... actually I have a billion other questions, but I'll check back tomorrow. **What's a good source that would help give understanding for all these questions, and all the followup questions that would surely derive from the previous?**

Answer (score 0):

After reading these answers, I was left personally more confused, as the given examples used everything but video examples. So I made my own answer. I hope this helps you (and others) understand.

Watch speed multiplier total time taken equation

t=Y/nZ
t=seconds
Y=total frames
Z=frames per second (fps)
n=watch speed multiplier

In this, we are assuming the video was filmed at 60fps and plays for 300 seconds at x1 speed. This gives us 18,000 frames. How many frames are in a given video won’t change, but the fps rate will change with your multiplier. So for the example video, the equation looks like this:

0.5x watch speed multiplier (half speed)
t=18,000/0.5*60
t=18,000/30
t=600 seconds (10 minutes)

1x watch speed multiplier (normal speed)
t=18,000/1*60
t=18,000/60
t=300 seconds (5 minutes)

2x watch speed multiplier (double speed)
t=18,000/2*60
t=18,000/120
t=150 seconds (2 minutes 30 seconds)

2.5x watch speed multiplier
t=18,000/2.5*60
t=18,000/150
t=120 seconds (2 minutes)

2.75x watch speed multiplier
t=18,000/2.75*60
t=18,000/165
t=109.09(repeating) seconds (1 minute 49.09(repeating) seconds)

As you can see, the overall time and the fps both change, but the total frames never do. This is because video is made of frames. A typical frame rate is 60fps. So to determine how long your video will last given a specific watch speed multiplier, you need to know what fps your video has at normal (1x) watch speed. Then you can take the seconds it lasts and multiply the two together for total frames. Once you solve for total frames, you can use the simple equation above to determine how long any video will play for, for any given watch speed multiplier.

Comment: Please use Mathjax

Comment: It seems the system likes to make a mess of line by line examples, so the equation and the examples got bunched up in a way I didn’t intend